# Change Explorer's View to Large Icons on 1 parent folder and all its child folders

Tags: windows

Who has a program to recursively change 1 subdir structure to Large Icons view?

e.g. I have a MyPics folder on a network drive in which I want to browse all the folders in it using Large Icons view. I want all other folders everywhere to use Details view, so setting Explorer to replicate the current view everywhere is not desirable;  nor is manually changing the 1,000+ folders in the MyPics structure to Large Icons view (and for 3 different Windows computers on my LAN, to boot).

**Why doesn't Explorer have a way to change a parent folder and all its child folders to the same view style ?**??

Windows 7 HP x64, for what it's worth, but no other versions of Windows have ever had this desirable option, either... that I'm aware of, anyway.

**unfortunately, what I said was not quite what I meant. :(

I wanted to change the subdirectory and all subdirs below that to **Extra Large Icons** view.**

Answer (score 2):

T clarify Malachi's answer:

1. Right-click folder.
2. Select the Customize tab.
3. Where it says 'Optimize this folder for:', select 'Pictures'.
4. Tick the box marked 'Also apply this template to all subfolders'.
5. Click OK.  All subfolders will now default to large icon view (tested on Win 7 & win 8).

Comment: Not working on my PC (Windows 10 version 1803)!

Answer (score 1):

This method works on at least [Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812003/EN-US):

1. Right-click folder
2. Select the *Customize* tab
3. Set the picture

Comment: no Need for a Signature

Answer (score -1):

In Windows 7/8 you can also set this view as the default for *all* folders of this view "type", e.g. picture folders.

This applies across all folders, not just those inside the hierarchy.

Everything else would still be detail view, or whatever you use for that.